# Examples of Smooth, Compact and Non-rigid Manifolds that Bound a Finite, Non-zero Volume

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Are there codimension-1 submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that are smooth everywhere and topological equivalent to a sphere with $0\le h\lt\infty$ handles and allow an isometric deformation, that continuously depends on a parameter $t$, (which could be interpreted as time) and/or, how can such manifolds be characterized?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an isometric deformation; do you mean "submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$" when you say "manifold"? Given your title, do you further mean hypersurfaces?

Comment: An isometric deformation is one that neither changes angles nor areas on the manifold during the deformation. A common example is the deformation of the helicoid to a catenoid; however the surfaces in that example are not of the topological type I have in mind. I hope the example clarifies my question. And, yes I mean hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, especially $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I don't have time to answer properly, but there is a substantial literature on this topic. One reference is a Sabitov paper entitled "Local Theory of Bending of Surfaces." Search for rigidity of surfaces of positive curvature.

Comment: For compact hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n \geq 4$,
see Theorem 6.14 at page 96 of
'Submanifolds and isometric immersions'
by Marcos Dajczer
Publish or Perish, 1990.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: I took the liberty to precise the question: for abstract Riemannian manifolds, an isometric deformation is precisely changing nothing.

Comment: I'm under the impression that there is no known example of a smooth closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that can be deformed isometrically as smooth surfaces. I believe it's a conjecture that in fact there are none and all smooth closed surfaces are rigid in the smooth category. And things only get more rigid in higher dimensions. This is in sharp contrast to polyhedral surfaces, where Connelly constructed a counterexample (and there is a metal model of it at IHES).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1975/is-a-smooth-closed-surface-in-euclidean-3-space-rigid

Comment: I wonder if Theorem 1 in the following paper can be helpful : http://www.mat.puc-rio.br/~earp/rigi7.pdf .

Comment: @Holonomia could you please make your comment an answer? It seems to answer my question.

Comment: I hesitated to answer due to fact that it not clear to me that the dependence on the parameter $\epsilon$ is smooth i.e. $C^{\infty}$ as is discussed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1975/is-a-smooth-closed-surface-in-euclidean-3-space-rigid

Comment: @Holonomia that may be true, but I only asked for continuity

Comment: In http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1975/is-a-smooth-closed-surface-in-euclidean-3-space-rigid, "smooth" is used only in terms of the regularity of the embedding and not in terms of the dependence of the embedding in terms of the parameter.

Comment: @Deane Yang as I interpret the answer in the cited MO question, continuous isometric deformation of smooth closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is always possible due to the theorem of Kuiper; if that is correct you might supply it as an answer. An example of such a deformation e.g. for the sphere would be great.

Comment: Manfred, you have to be careful about what you're saying is smooth or not. Kuiper's theorem says that given a smooth Riemannian 2-manifold, there is an infinite family of $C^1$ isometric embeddings of the surface into $\mathbb{R}^3$. So the Riemannian manifold is smooth, but as a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 1 in the following paper: http://www.mat.puc-rio.br/~earp/rigi7.pdf
assert to construct examples of compact genus $g$ surfaces $\bar{M}_{k,\epsilon} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ all isometric (but not congruent) to a fix $\bar{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. It seems to me that the dependence on the parameter $\epsilon$ is not continuous as the OP asked. But perhaps I am misunderstanding Theorem 1.