# "Inflating" a closed, defined metric, manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometric-immersion

Consider a two-dimensional Riemannian manifold homeomorphic to the sphere, with a defined metric.

Since we do not suppose that manifold to have a positive curvature, 
we are not in the hypotheses of the Pogorelov's uniqueness theorem. 
As a consequnce, in general, there are many possible isometric embeddings in $\mathbb R^3$ for that manifold.

The question is the following: is the maximum volume embedding 
of that manifold unique, up to rigid transformations?

The problem can be expressed in a more intuitive way:
Suppose we have an inflatable object whose walls can be bent but not stretched.
It can be seen as a closed manifold of known metric.
If I inflate such an object until I reach the maximum volume, 
is the resulting object rigid? (suppose that there aren't
narrow bottlenecks that could divide the object
into two or more parts).

Comment: Isn't there a problem with the existence of a maximizer, in this generality?

Comment: @PietroMajer: I am not sure i understood your comment. Do you mean that the problem needs more hypotheses to ensure that a maximum volume embedding could even exist? Probably yes, suggestions for restricting the generality of the problem are well accepted.

Comment: It’s in fact conjectured that *any* closed smooth surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is rigid. There was a similar conjecture for polyhedra, but Connelly found a counterexample.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I think that the Connely sphere  (as well as the Steffen's polyhedron)
is not the maximum volume polyedron that you can obtain with the same set of fixed-length
edges. You can turn outward a part of that polyedron (by preserving the edges' length) and get a rigid one.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Probably you mean that _any_ _convex_ closed surface is rigid (Pogorelov's theorem)

Comment: Nope. Rigidity of convex surfaces is, as you say, a theorem. For nonconvex, it’s a conjecture. No counterexample is known.

Comment: Sorry about the vague statement. I meant only that Connelly’s polyhedron is flexible. In that situation your question about maximum volume is an interest one.

Comment: For submetric embeddings (e.g. "inflatable objects" whose walls can compress but not stretch), some related conjectures and problems are discussed in these papers of Pak and Pak and Schlenker: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/pillow4 https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S140292511000057X

Comment: @DeaneYang: Maybe I didn't consider the importance of the smoothness of the embedding. 
Can you give some reference about that conjecture?

Comment: @PFerro, I don't remember where I first heard about this, but I did post the question on MathOverflow several years ago and others were able to provide some references. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1975/is-a-smooth-closed-surface-in-euclidean-3-space-rigid

Comment: I think it's really cool but extremely difficult conjecture. There is no way to use existing PDE technology to answer this question. The only approach I ever thought about, I think it was suggested to me by Dennis Sullivan, was to try smooth Connelly's counterexample. You just need to construct smooth analogues of the vertices.

Comment: @PFerro: I am vaguely thinking to a situation like this. Let $I:=\, ]-1,1[$ and let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with smooth boundary,  and suppose that $U\cap I^3$ is the hypograph of a smooth, nonpositive function with compact support $\phi:I^2\to I$, that is  $U\cap I^3=\{(x,y,z)\in I^3: z<\phi(x,y)\}$. If e.g. $U$ is convex, changing the sign of $\phi$ produces a larger open set $U'$, with  $\text{Vol}(U')=\text{Vol}(U)+2\int|\phi|$ and with $\partial U'$ isometric to $\partial U$. But if $U$ was not convex, this operation may produce a self-intersection.

Comment: (above I mean "if e.g. $U$ is *starshaped*).  Anyway, the point is, after inflating an object with non-positive curvature, some parts of it may touch each other, no?

Comment: @PietroMajer: 1) (I'm not sure I understood) OK, it _may_ produce self intersections, but not necessarely. 2) This is intersting! I didnt consider that by inflating the object some parts of it may touch each other. Suppose they don't, this simplifies the problem.